# How to change footnote number style

Tags: fonts, footnotes, luatex, oldstylenums

I use old-style numerals as the default text font, but that also makes the footnote numbers old-style---which I don't want.

How can change  the footnote numbers to lining figures?

I'm using LuaLaTeX and Adobe Garamond Pro.

Comment: Alan, the realscripts package isn't working.  Two files were installed: realscripts.sty and realscripts.tpm. I then used \usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}. The result: the footnote numbers were set on the baseline, both in the body of the text and at the bottom of the page. And, they were still old-style, instead of the special superscript glyphs that Adobe Garamond has. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just load the [`realscripts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/realscripts) package.  It defaults to regular numbers.

Here's a minimal test document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage{realscripts}

\begin{document}
This is some text.\footnote{A footnote} Some more text.

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}Lining Numbers: 1234567} OldStyle Numbers: 1234567
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Alan, I can't get this package to work.

Comment: @Bob I've edited my answer to include a minimal document. Does that produce the same output for you? (I've artificially squished the placement of the actual footnote in the image.) If not, there's something wrong with your installation. If it does, then you'll need to investigate other aspects of your actual document that are the source of the problem.  What document class are you using?

Comment: OK, I found the problem. Not too long ago, I discovered that I wasn't getting ligatures, so I added Renderer=Basic in the 
\setmainfont statement. When I just now removed it, realscripts worked like a charm, and I'm still getting ligatures. (I updated Miktex 2.9 yesterday, so maybe that corrected the problem I had with ligatures.)  So now everything's fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.  Since it helped to solve the problem you should accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.