# Cannot set lining numbers in footnotes with realscripts and Times New Roman font

Tags: fonts, xetex, footnotes, fontspec

Whereas loading the package `realscripts` will change the footnote markers to lining numbers in some fonts (cf. [How to change footnote number style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19323/how-to-change-footnote-number-style/19325#19325)), it does not work with Times New Roman:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\TNR[Numbers=Lining]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\begin{document}
0123456789\footnote{Word}
{\TNR{0123456789\footnote{Word}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm wondering, therefore, if there is some alternative way of setting the footnote marks to be lining numbers with fonts where `realscripts` has no effect. By renewing the macro `\footnotemark` or something ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched Times New Roman to Latin Modern Roman because my copy of TNR only has lining figures and both fonts lack real superscripts. This shows the effect of setting the font used for the footnotemark halfway through the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\llf[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\lpf[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\ltf[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\begin{document}
0123456789\footnote{Word}%               BEFORE

{\llf{0123456789\footnote{Word}}}

{\lpf 0123456789\footnote{Word}}

{\ltf 0123456789\footnote{Word}}

\renewcommand{\footnotemarkfont}{\lpf}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

0123456789\footnote{Word}%               AFTER

{\llf{0123456789\footnote{Word}}}

{\lpf 0123456789\footnote{Word}}

{\ltf 0123456789\footnote{Word}}
\end{document}
```

[image]